# ipcluster - can't start more than about 110 ipengines - or maybe some of them die

Tags: ipython-parallel

I'm having difficulty getting ipcluster to start all of the ipengines that I ask for.  It appears to be some sort of timeout issue.  I'm using IPython 2.0 on a linux cluster with 192 processors.  I run a local ipcontroller, and start ipengines on my 12 nodes using SSH.  It's not a configuration problem (at least I don't think it is) because I'm having no problems running about 110 ipengines.  When I try for a larger amount, some of them seem to die during start up, and I do mean some of them - the final number I have varies a little. ipcluster reports that all engines have started.  The only sign of trouble that I can find (other than not having use of all of the requested engines) is the following in some of the ipengine logs:

```
2014-06-20 16:42:13.302 [IPEngineApp] Loading url_file u'.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-engine.json'
2014-06-20 16:42:13.335 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://10.1.0.253:55576
2014-06-20 16:42:13.429 [IPEngineApp] Starting to monitor the heartbeat signal from the hub every 3010 ms.
2014-06-20 16:42:13.434 [IPEngineApp] Using existing profile dir: u'.ipython/profile_ssh'
2014-06-20 16:42:13.436 [IPEngineApp] Completed registration with id 49
2014-06-20 16:42:25.472 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (1 time(s) in a row).
2014-06-20 18:09:12.782 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (1 time(s) in a row).
2014-06-20 19:14:22.760 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (1 time(s) in a row).
2014-06-20 20:00:34.969 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (1 time(s) in a row).
```

I did some googling to see if I could find some wisdom, and the only thing I've come across is http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ipython.devel/12228.  The author seems to think it's a timeout of sorts.

I also tried tripling (90 seconds as opposed to the default 30) the IPClusterStart.early_shutdown and IPClusterEngines.early_shutdown times without any luck.

Thanks - in advance - for any pointers on getting the full use of my cluster.

Comment: Hi, I have came across the same problem, have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When I try execute ipcluster start --n=200 I get: OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
This could be what happens to you too. Try raising the open file limit of the OS.

Comment: ulimit -n reports that I have a limit of 1024 files, so I don't think that is the problem.  Please let me know if this isn't the correct diagnostic

Comment: Also... I can run two different ipclusters - both with 96 threads - concurrently.  I assume this would violate the number of open files limit if that was the problem.